# sharing a global var through vue and electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, electron-vue

I had been using electron-vue and I met a few problems when I tried to share a set of global vars through electron and vue.
I have tried vuex and i found that changes made in the main process(electron) doesn't appear in chrome process (values are different).
I have also tried electron-vue but it cant trigger vue's update.

Comment: Solved by using observer and IPC

Answer (score 0):

I just use electron (in devdependencies) and vue, vuex (in dependencies). No code is needed in the main Electron JS file (your main.js or app.js). I do like this :

index.html (main window) :

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

index.js :

```
const Vuex = require('vuex');

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        // your global variables
        var1: 'test',
        var2: true
        },
    mutations: {
        setVar(state, data) {
            state[data.mykey] = data.val;
            } // setpref
        } // mutations
    }); // store
```

in any other renderer js or component :

```
// no require needed except vue.js done in html

computed: {
    // Variable got from the global store
    var1: function () { 
        return this.$store.state.var1; 
        }
    },

methods: {
    foo: function () {
        // changing global store variable
        this.$store.commit('setVar', {mykey: 'var1', val: 'test2'});
        },
```